# Full SQL statement logging on Dropwizard

Tags: sql, sql-server, dropwizard, jdbi

I've a Dropwizard application using JDBI and SQL Server. I would like to get all SQL statements logged with their parameters but I don't seem to be able to.

This is what's usually recommended to do:

`logging:
  level: INFO
  loggers:
    "org.skife": TRACE
    "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc": TRACE`

But this only logs statements, without the parameters:

`TRACE [2016-07-08 16:40:27,711] org.skife.jdbi.v2.DBI: statement:[/* LocationDAO.detail */ EXEC [api].[GetCountryCodes] @CountryId = ?] took 487 millis
DEBUG [2016-07-08 16:37:44,499] com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.Connection: ENTRY /* LocationDAO.detail */ EXEC [api].[GetCountryCodes] @CountryId = ?`

Is there any way to get the actual statement run against the database?

Comment: Have a look at this question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23564383/how-to-print-the-sqlquery-annotation-in-jdbi-sql-api/30549524#30549524

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [p6spy](https://github.com/p6spy/p6spy) seems to be the easiest way to go. Just add the dependency:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>p6spy</groupId>
   <artifactId>p6spy</artifactId>
   <version>2.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

On the database config, use the p6spy class instead and slightly modify your connection url

```yaml
database:
  driverClass: com.p6spy.engine.spy.P6SpyDriver
  url: jdbc:p6spy:sqlserver://10.0.82.95;Database=psprd1
```

Comment: Use the following flag to redirect output to console -Dp6spy.config.appender=com.p6spy.engine.spy.appender.StdoutLogger
Details here https://p6spy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configandusage.html#command-line-options