# Logging SQL statements in Spring Boot + jdbi

Tags: spring, logging, spring-boot, jdbi

I'm using datasource with DBI:

```
@Autowired
DataSource dataSource;

@Bean
public DBI dbiBean() {
    DBI dbi = new DBI(dataSource);
    return dbi;
}
```

I have no idea how to configure logging framework to log SQL statements. I tried:

```
logging:
 level: 
   org.hibernate: TRACE
   org.skife.jdbi: TRACE
   java.sql: TRACE
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: In which class did you create `Bean` object?, I think it should be set in `*Application` class which contains main method.

Comment: In one of spring @Config class. I found how to log SQL statements, but my solution not show SQL params

Comment: @MarcinWiśniewski perhaps you should share what you found

Comment: Ok, it is necessary to call dbi.setSQLLog(new SLF4JLog());

Comment: Have seen that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23564383/how-to-print-the-sqlquery-annotation-in-jdbi-sql-api ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Starting from JDBI version 3.2.0, [SqlLogger](http://jdbi.org/apidocs/org/jdbi/v3/core/statement/SqlLogger.html) interface should be used:

```java
  Jdbi jdbi;
  jdbi.setSqlLogger(new Slf4JSqlLogger());
```

As documentation says, [Slf4JSqlLogger](http://jdbi.org/apidocs/org/jdbi/v3/core/statement/Slf4JSqlLogger.html) is a simple SqlLogger that emits some diagnostic information about Jdbi usage. You can provide existing instance of Slf4J `Logger` class to the `Slf4JSqlLogger` constructor then  the provided logger will be used to log SQL statements, otherwise, if no-args constructor is used, a logger called `org.jdbi.sql` will be created and used.

SQL statements are logged with `debug` log level, so in order to see them it might be necessary to set the root level of the logging framework to `debug`.

Answer (score 3):

Add the line to set the SQL log like this. Use either SLF4JLog or another logger there.

```
@Bean
public DBI dbiBean() {
    DBI dbi = new DBI(dataSource);
    dbi.setSQLLog(new SLF4JLog());
    return dbi;
}
```

Comment: I think this is specific to JDBI 2. Doesn't work with JDBI 3.